# Change `font-family` in Angular Chart.js

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, font-family, angular-chart

How to change `font-family` in [Angular Chart](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js) and set a custom font for labels?

Comment: @ℊααnd For all text, label, tooltips

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a custom font-family for the chart, in the following way ...

```
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Verdana';
```

add this, at the beginning of your script (before initializing the app)